# Refresh page until value changes in Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to validate that a value changes to the correct text and if it does not to refresh the page and check again for up to set time.

I have tried while-loops, if statements and nested variations of both with no success. I am not even sure how to format it as this point.

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('xpath')
While True:
   if element contains textA
     break
   else if element contains textB
    driver.refresh()
   else
     error
```

Something along those lines. Ignore any syntax errors, I am just trying to get the idea across

I have also tried using EC and By with no luck

Edit: Adding some details

So what I have is a table. I am inserting a new row with no problems. Then I need to check that one of the column values of the new row gets updated from 'new' to 'old' which usually takes about anywhere from 30secs to 2mins. This is all viewable from a web ui. I need to refresh the page in order to see the value change. I wish I had some more detailed code or error to post along with it but honestly I am just beginning to learn Selenium

Comment: Please post the error you are getting as well.

Comment: Can you share what you've tried? Which part are you struggling with, specifically?

Comment: no specific errors. The test either runs to completion with a false positive, gives syntax errors, or gets stuck in a perceptual loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please try the following :

```
    while True:
        try:
            driver.find_element_by_xpath('xpath'):
        except NoSuchElementException:
            driver.refresh
        else:
            print("Text found")
            break
```

**Note:** I suggest to create text-based XPath to avoid an extra line of code to get and compare text.

Comment: This works except that the element always exists, but I am looking for the text to change. I also cant look for the specific text casue duplicates can exist at any given time. Its a text value within a grid that i want to make sure updates correctly and in a timely matter

Comment: If you can't look for specific text, how we can make sure text changed?

Comment: That is the question. I tried your code and it ran but gave a false positive. It found the text i was looking elsewhere in the page but not in the specific location I was looking

Comment: But for specific location, you should give specific xpath I would say. for example xpath which point specific TD tag in table.

Comment: Also i am getting an error saying that NoSuchElementException is not defined. Do i need to import a package? I almost got it working i think. I added [contains(text(), 'txt'] to the find xpath

Comment: Just add this line : `from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException`

Comment: Make sure to check for x number of seconds, otherwise the script might end-up with infinite loop if text is not found (not loaded)/changed.